# Preview different text when CheckBoxes are changed

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I did not find any solution to my problem, perhaps it is because I cannot express correctly what I really want to do.
Basically, I have 4 `CheckBoxes` and when some of them are checked, I want to add some text to a `TextBox` with multiple lines.

Example:

```
If checkbox1.checked = true then
     Textbox1.text = text1
Elseif checkbox1.checked = true and checkbox2.checked = true then
     Textbox1.text = text1 & vbCrLf & text2
Elseif checkbox1.checked = true and checkbox2.checked = true and checkbox3.checked = true then
     Textbox1.text = text1 & vbCrLf & text2 & vbCrLf & text3    
Elseif checkbox1.checked = true and checkbox3.checked = true then
     textbox1.text = text1 & vbCrLf & text3
End if
```

I know there is a logical error in the code (If i have 4 `CheckBoxes` checked it will show only `text1` rather than `text1 & vbCrLf & text2 & vbCrLf & text3 & vbCrLf & text4`) but I do not know how to express my problem in another way.

If I check the first and the third `CheckBoxes` I want to see `text1` and `text3` accordingly, do I have to hard code every single possible way I could check the `CheckBoxes` or is there a way to automatically add the text I need on a new line?

Comment: Don't use "else if". Each checkbox should be in an "if....end if" by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another method that can handle any number of `CheckBoxes` as source and any kind of Control as Output (provided that the Output Control has a `Text` property).

Build a list of the strings used to compose the Output text.

Declare it:

```
Private ChechBoxesText As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
```

then fill it, when appropriate:
(the source of the strings can be anything that can be converted to/viewed as an `Array(Of String)`)

```
ChechBoxesText.AddRange({"Text1", "Text2", "Text3", "Text4", "Text5"})
```

Add a common handler for the `CheckedChanged` event to all the `CheckBoxes`:

```
For Each ctl As CheckBox In Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox).ToList
    AddHandler ctl.CheckedChanged, AddressOf CheckBoxes_CheckedChanged
Next
```

**Note:**
The `CheckBox` controls could also be located inside another container (`GroupBox`, `Panel` etc.). In this case, the collection considered will be (when the container is a `GroupBox`):

```
Controls("GroupBox1").Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox)
```

Define the Handler, which will call a Function specifying the Control that will receive the Output:
Here it's a `TextBox` control, but it could also be a `RichTextBox`, a `Label`, a `Button` (...).

```
Private Sub CheckBoxes_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    RebuilText(TextBox1)
End Sub

Private Sub RebuilText(OutPut As Control)

    OutPut.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox).
                         Where(Function(c) c.Checked = True).
                         OrderBy(Function(c) c.Name.Length).
                         ThenBy(Function(c) c.Name).
                         Select(Function(c) ChechBoxesText(CInt(c.Name.Substring("CheckBox".Length)) - 1)))
End Sub
```

---

A description of the **`LINQ`** methods used:

Using the current Form's Collection of Controls of Type `CheckBox` as source:

```
Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox)
```

[**`Where()`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Linq.Enumerable.Where);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2) filters the Collection, considering only Controls of Type `CheckBox` that are currently `Checked`:

```
Where(Function(c) c.Checked = True)
```

`c` is one of the elements of the source Collection. A `CheckBox` control, in this case.

[**`OrderBy()`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netframework-4.7.2) Orders the Collection by `Control.Name.Length` first, then by the `Control.Name` string.
This will order the Controls by their Name and the trailing number (`CheckBox`**1**, `CheckBox`**2**, `CheckBox`**11**).
If we don't order by `Name.Lenght` first, `CheckBox`**11** will appear before `CheckBox`**2** in the sort order.

```
OrderBy(Function(c) c.Name.Length).
ThenBy(Function(c) c.Name).
```

[**`Select()`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.7.2) is a *transformation* method. It allows to return a different type or value.
In this case, it will return the string contained in the `ChechBoxesText` `List(Of String)`.
The `List(Index)` position is extracted from the `CheckBox.Name` trailing number, converted to an `Integer`:

```
Select(Function(c) ChechBoxesText(CInt(c.Name.Substring("CheckBox".Length)) - 1)))
```

Here, the **`Substring(StartIndex)`** method will return a new String from the `CheckBox.Name`, starting from the `"CheckBox".Length` position to `CheckBox.Name.Length`.

You could also use a **`CheckBox.Tag`** property to store the Index of the related Text in the `ChechBoxesText` List.
In this case, the `Select()` method would be:

```
Select(Function(c) ChechBoxesText(Convert.ToInt32(c.Tag))))
```

Comment: I just tried this, and I am getting this error "OfType is not a member of 'Control.ControlCollection'."

Comment: @n0degg  See: [Enumerable.OfType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype). This code, as jmcihinney's, requires a reference to [System.Linq](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq?view=netframework-4.7.2). If you don't have this reference (manually deselected?), open you Project Properties -> References and locate `System.Linq` in the `Imported Namespaces` panel (and tick it, of course :).

Comment: I was using net framework 3, that's why I was getting this error. Just recreated the project and everything is working fine, thanks a lot. @Jimi

Comment: @n0degg  About the .Net FrameWork: as a suggestion, possibly avoid `4.6.0`. Use `4.7.1` or `4.7.2`, if the OS supports them.

Answer (score 3):

What I would suggest is that you start by assigning the text that corresponds to each `CheckBox` to the `Tag` property of that `CheckBox`.  You can do that in the designer.  You can then just get a list of checked boxes, get the text for each one and join them together, e.g.

```
Dim checkBoxes = {CheckBox1, CheckBox2, CheckBox3, CheckBox4}

TextBox1.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine,
                            checkBoxes.Where(Function(cb) cb.Checked).
                                       Select(Function(cb) CStr(cb.Tag)))
```

That creates a list of all `CheckBoxes`, filters it to only the checked ones, gets the text for each of those and then joins those substrings into a single `String` using line breaks as delimiters.  For those who prefer LINQ query syntax to function syntax:

```
Dim checkBoxes = {CheckBox1, CheckBox2, CheckBox3, CheckBox4}

TextBox1.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine,
                            From cb In checkBoxes
                            Where cb.Checked
                            Select CStr(cb.Tag))
```

If you don't want to go the LINQ route then you can go with a more conventional loop:

```
Dim checkBoxes = {CheckBox1, CheckBox2, CheckBox3, CheckBox4}
Dim substrings As New List(Of String)

For Each cb In checkBoxes
    If cb.Checked Then
        substrings.Add(CStr(cb.Tag))
    End If
Next

TextBox1.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, substrings)
```

Comment: For the non-LINQ method, I am getting this error **"BC30311 Value of type 'List(Of String)' cannot be converted to 'String()'."**. As for the first method I gave value to the property tag but when I run it and try to preview the text(by clicking a button), I am getting an error again **"System.MissingMemberException: 'Public member 'Where' on type 'CheckBox()' not found.'"** When I try the LINQ syntax, this is the error i get **"Expression of type 'Object' is not queryable. Make sure you are not missing an assembly reference and/or namespace import for the LINQ provider."**

Comment: It appears that you are using .NET 3.5 or earlier.  The `String.Join` method only accepted a `String` array prior to .NET 4.0, which added several new overloads.  It's generally a good idea to say so if you're targeting an older version.  Note that you can call `ToArray` on a `List(Of T)` to get the required array.

Comment: Good old Tag property; handy as a pants pocket.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use "else if". Each checkbox should be in an "if....end if" by itself.

```
Textbox1.Text = ""
FinalText = ""

If checkbox1.checked = true then
     FinalText = text1 & vbCrLf
End If
If checkbox2.checked = true then
     FinalText = FinalText & text2 & vbCrLf
End If
...

Textbox1.Text = FinalText
```

etc.

Comment: So I still have to do it for each situation?

Comment: Edits should have to be made to code that was posted as an answer.  I recommend updating the answer if possible.

Comment: Thanks for the code correction, guys. I should not code when I'm tired and this is proof!